# Solving a limit

Tags: limits

Pardon me for this trivial question but shouldnt the limit be -7? Cuz the answer sheet says it should be -5.
Thanks for help
$$\lim_{x \to -2^+} f(x) $$
where
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x - 5&x= -2\\4x+1&\text{otherwise}\\\end{cases}$$

Comment: And sorry for the crappy latex job.

Comment: Yes. The limit is -7

Comment: Yes and thank you.

Comment: You are correct. The limit is $-7$.  Also, thanks @PeterForeman for the nice job editing.

Comment: In fact, $\lim_{x\to -2} f(x) = -7$; it's the same, whether approaching -2 from the left or right.  The only way the limit could be $-5$ is if "otherwise" $f(x) = 3x+1$".

Comment: I thank you all.